Incorporating Inline or External JavaScript in Content Hub's OOTB HTML Component
Can we embed or add inline JavaScript or external JavaScript files in Content Hub's Out-of-the-Box (OOTB) HTML component? The objective is to create a straightforward HTML component with a small snippet of JavaScript code. Despite attempts, it's not functioning as expected.
I am aware that we can use external react component but I want to make it simple as its a very basic html+Javascript component

You have external components just for the purpose that you described. I don't think HTML components can fire JavaScript.
Except its a few more clicks, external components provide the flexibility to embed the client-side code of your choice.
What is the exact concern with using external components?
